# Returning linked list structs from a C function

Tags: c, struct

I've reached my wits end with this issue. I have a rather large C program that's currently giving me segmentation faults when It's supposed to return.

```
    struct customer{
    char *name;
    int custID;
    double credit;
    char *address;
    char *state;
    char *zip;
};
typedef struct customer customer;

struct custNode{
    customer *customer;
    struct custNode *next;
};
typedef struct custNode custNode;
```

// . . .

```
custNode *customerList = (custNode *)malloc(sizeof(custNode));
readDatabase(fp,customerList);
```

So the read database funtion is reading strings from a file in the same directory and making a linked list of custNodes out of it. It seems that my code isn't attaching the custNodes to the front of the list properly and I have no idea why. It breaks at the return statement in the readDatabase function.

```
void attachCustNode(custNode *head, customer *target){
    if(!target || !head){
        printf("\nTarget or Head is NULL!!!\n");
    }
    custNode *temp = malloc(sizeof(custNode));
    temp->customer = target ;

    if(!head->customer){
        printf("building new list\n");
        temp->next = head;
        *head = *temp;
    }
    else{
        printf("ELSE attaching to front\n");
        temp->next = NULL;
        *head = *temp;
    }
    return;
}



void readDatabase(FILE *fp , custNode *result){ //reads the database file for the customers
    printf("reading database, creating structures.\n");
    int i , size;
    size_t fSize; //getline wants size_t ... dumb.
    char *buff,*tok;
    unsigned int error = 1;
    char delim[3] = "|\"";
    delim[2] = '\0';

    result->customer = NULL;
    result->next = NULL;

    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(fp);
    fSize = size;
    fseek(fp , 0 , SEEK_SET) ; //get size of file, reset fseek
    printf("database of  size %d \n", size);
    buff = malloc( (sizeof(char)*size)+1);
    /*
    printf("Buffer is %s and error is %d  \n", buff, error);
    if( error <= 0 ){
        printf("getline fell and couldn't get up in %s on line %d\n", __FILE__ , __LINE__);
        break;
    }
    */
    //int len;
    while( error > 0 ){
        error = getline(&buff, &fSize, fp);
        if( error < 0 ){
            printf("breaking loop\n");
            break;
        }
        customer *temp = (customer *)malloc(sizeof(customer));
        tok = strtok(buff , delim);
        temp->name = tok;
        tok = strtok(NULL, delim);
        temp->custID = atoi(tok); ///int atoi(const char *nptr);
        tok = strtok(NULL, delim);
        temp->credit = atof(tok); //double atof(const char *nptr);
        //printf("added %lf to temp orderNode\n",temp->credit); //%f prints doubles.
        tok = strtok(NULL, delim);
        temp->address = tok;
        tok = strtok(NULL, delim);
        temp->state = tok;
        tok = strtok(NULL, delim);
        temp->zip = tok;
        attachCustNode(result,temp);
    }
    return ;
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

EDIT. I've posted my code in this github gist to make it easier, It still for some reason won't exit the function. I added the strdup function on line 148 etc as suggested by the responses but for some reason it's still not returning.

https://gist.github.com/DavidAwad/006489d0648474a1a7e5

Comment: can u run it with valgrind?

Comment: and a clue about where it goes bang would be nice

Comment: read the entire file into memory and no malloc check? Seems odd to alloc buffer for whole file then loop over it with getline

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic used in `attachCustNode` is faulty.

`head` always points to the same location in memory. Let's say it's value is `H`.

When the list is empty:

```
head       =   H
temp->next =   H
*head = *temp;
```

That means:

```
head       =   H
head->next =   H
```

What you need is

```
head->next =   NULL
```

Also, at this point, `temp` is memory leak.

When the list is not empty:

```
temp->next = NULL;
*head = *temp;
```

This makes

```
head       =   H
head->next =   NULL
```

At this point, `temp` is memory leak.

The strategy you are using to determine whether the list is empty is faulty. Instead of

```
if(!head->customer){
```

you should refactor your code to not even worry about whether the list is empty.

Here's the refactored code:

```
custNode* attachCustNode(custNode* head, customer *target){

    custNode *temp = malloc(sizeof(custNode));
    temp->customer = target;

    // No matter what head is temp is now the head.
    temp->next = head;
    return temp;
}
```

Refactor `readDatabase` a bit too. Return the newly created list instead of passing a pointer.

```
custNode* readDatabase(FILE *fp){ //reads the database file for the customers
    custNode *result = NULL;

    // Your code
    // ....

    while( error > 0 ){
       // Your code
       // ....
       result = attachCustNode(result, temp);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Refactor `main` to account for the change to `readDatabase`.

```
custNode *customerList = readDatabase(fp);
```

**Update**

Some of these lines are not right. You are pointing to memory that is not valid after you return from the function. You need to allocate memory for the strings and use `strcpy` or simply use `strdup`.

```
    customer *temp = (customer *)malloc(sizeof(customer));
    tok = strtok(buff , delim);
    temp->name = tok;               // NOT GOOD
    tok = strtok(NULL, delim);
    temp->custID = atoi(tok);
    tok = strtok(NULL, delim);
    temp->credit = atof(tok);
    tok = strtok(NULL, delim);
    temp->address = tok;           // NOT GOOD
    tok = strtok(NULL, delim);
    temp->state = tok;             // NOT GOOD
    tok = strtok(NULL, delim);
    temp->zip = tok;               // NOT GOOD
```

Use:

```
    temp->name = strdup(tok);
```

Make similar changes for the members `address`, `state`, and `zip`.

Comment: i made the changes and i understand them completely, but for some reason it's still not working. It seg faults when i'm returning out of main. Here's a link to a github gist if you have any other ideas please feel free. Thank you so much.  https://gist.github.com/DavidAwad/006489d0648474a1a7e5

Comment: Ahh I see, right someone pointed that out too. But its valid for my integer and double right?

Comment: @Smashking, yes, it is valid for integer and double. You are welcome.

Comment: So what happens if temp->name is too small for the string its taking in? Does strdup re allocate the buffer for me? Or do I have to realloc?

Comment: @Smashking, `strdup` is a non-standard function that some platforms support. It will allocate enough memory to hold the input string. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html.

Comment: added the strdup functions, still not returning. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Smashking, the next step would be to scale down the program. Start from something small, make sure it works OK before adding new functionality. Add new functionality incrementally and test it before adding further functionality.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose this tiny piece of code is not doing what you want:

```
result->customer == NULL;
result->next == NULL;
```

Maybe

```
result->customer = NULL;
result->next = NULL;
```

? Then your if-Statement in *attachCustNode()* will work and the list items should be added.

Answer (score 2):

I see at least one problem:
the pointers that strtok returns are pointers into buff (read buffer)
these are saved in each customer structure.
But on the next read (getline) the input buffer (buff) gets wiped out,
and the pointers that were saved into the customer structures are now pointing into who knows what.

You need to either allocate memory for each name, address, state, zip,
or make them char arrays in your customer structure itself.

I dont know how you are getting a segfault,
but one way is when you free() buff (as you should, even if it's not shown)
all your pointers in all customer structures will become invalid.

Answer (score 0):

dont do this

```
   tok = strtok(NULL, delim);
    temp->address = tok;
```

do

```
  tok = strtok(NULL, delim);
    temp->address = strdup(tok);
```

strtok is returning a pointer to some location somewhere in buff, that may or maynot continue to exist. Strdup will make of copy of the string for you into malloced memory - you must free it

Comment: It would help if you explained your answer

Answer (score 0):

The answer was actually unrelated to this. :/ I was using the getline function and it was being set to an unsigned int so It was never negative.